# Laravel 5 foreign key won't be created

Tags: database, laravel, migration

Laravel 5 won't create a foreign key on my migration files:
I followed the documentation here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade and it does not work. The tables get created without the constraints

```
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Comments extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments',function($newTable){
        $newTable->increments('id');
        $newTable->integer('painting_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
        $newTable->integer('user_id');
        $newTable->text('comment');
        $newTable->date('crated')->default(Carbon::now());
        $newTable->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('comments',function($table){
        $table->foreign('painting_id')->references('id')->on('paintings')->onDelete('cascade');
    });


}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('comments');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the table to Innodb engine.
Add this at the end of the table creation.

```
Schema::create('comments',function($newTable){
 //The other fields
     $newTable->engine = "InnoDB";        
});
```